# Why won't GDI let me delete large images?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-io, gdi, locked-files

My ASP.NET application has an image cropping and resizing features. This requires that the uploaded temporary image be deleted. Everything works fine, but when I try to delete an image larger than 80px by 80px I get a "File is locked by another process..." error, even though I've released all resources.

Here's a snippet:

```
System.Drawing.Image tempimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(temppath);
System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image) tempimg.Clone(); //advice from another forum
tempimg.Dispose();

img = resizeImage(img, 200, 200); //delete only works if it's 80, 80
img.Save(newpath);
img.Dispose();

File.Delete(temppath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not disposing the first Image instance assigned to the img variable.

Consider this instead:

```
System.Drawing.Image tempimg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(temppath);
System.Drawing.Image img = (System.Drawing.Image) tempimg.Clone();
tempimg.Dispose();

System.Drawing.Image img2 = resizeImage(img, 200, 200);
img2.Save(newpath);
img2.Dispose();
img.Dispose();

File.Delete(temppath);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create the image this way, it won't be locked:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(info.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
                    int read = fs.Read(data, 0, (int)fs.Length);
                    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data, false);
                    return Image.FromStream(ms, false, false); // prevent GDI from holding image file open
                }
```

Comment: This code is not correct. The documentation for Image.FromStream states "You must keep the stream open for the lifetime of the Image." The above code does not do that. And, if it did do that, the file would remain locked.

Comment: I edited my answer. Now you have a stream which remains open and the file won't be locked.